# Why can't this simple function run on this object in this javascript state machine?

Tags: javascript, node.js, state-machine, stately.js

I am using the Stately.js state machine for node.js

https://github.com/fschaefer/Stately.js/

I start with a simple example.

```
var fsm = Stately.machine({
    'START': {
        // event: function () {
        // }
    },
    'NEXT_STATE': {
        // event: function () {
        // }
    },
});

fsm.setMachineState(fsm.NEXT_STATE);
```

I get the error `TypeError: fsm.setMachineState is not a function`. What can be wrong?

Comment: Have you verified that Stately.js has loaded correctly?

Comment: Yes. When I run `fsm.getMachineState()`, it works.

Comment: Follow the docs. You can call `setMachineState` only on the `this` reference inside an action, follow their example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not change the state from outside the state machine. You need the events on the current state to change to another state.

Comment: This seems to be the limitation of the state machine. I have used other state machines which allows me to do so. Thanks. Upvoted.

Comment: I believe this is a better implementation because you are not able to switch to a different state form "outside the machine". Look at it like this: you have a DVD player and you can put it into the Pause state while it is not turned on, there is no disc loaded and there is nothing playing.

Answer (score 1):

I have found some **hacky solution** that's allow you to change state outside of `this` reference in the state machine, in case you do not want to change the fsm library.

Instead of normal state transition, you can define you own function

by adding this function to each state

```
'setState': function(stateName){
  return this[stateName]
}
```

now your state will look like this and now can set state from outside of the state machine

```
var fsm = Stately.machine({
    'START': {
        'do_something': /* => */ 'NEXT_STATE',
        'setState': function(stateName){
            return this[stateName]
        }
    },
    'NEXT_STATE': {
        'setState': function(stateName){
            return this[stateName]
        }
    },
});

fsm.setState('YOUR_STATE_NAME');
```